# PHP code to return image from database

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am fairly new to php and am having some trouble trying to get my images to populate correctly from my database. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is my current code. It is currently returning my default image and not my product image if in the database.

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT products.giftID, products.gift_name, products.price, products.short_description, product_image.picture FROM products LEFT JOIN product_image ON product_image.giftID='products.giftID' AND products.vendorID='1'";                                 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Database access failed:".mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($row['picture'] == '') {
        echo "<img src=product_img/image_coming_soon.jpg>";
    } else {
        echo "<img src='".$row['picture'] ."'>";
    }                                       
}
?>
```

Formatting the query for readability:

```
SELECT products.giftID, products.gift_name, products.price,
       products.short_description, 
       product_image.picture
  FROM products
  LEFT JOIN product_image ON product_image.giftID='products.giftID'
                         AND products.vendorID='1'
```

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: To troubleshoot, what's the actual value of `$row['picture']`?

Comment: Then it would appear that `$row['picture'] == ''` is true.  Are you sure your database has the data you expect?

Comment: it is the path to the folder containing the image.  for example:  product_img/image_name.jpg

Comment: If that's the case, the `else` part would be executed. Are you sure that's the value?

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: Yes, for example giftID 1 has a value of product_img/giftID_1_.jpg

Comment: `<img src=product_img/image_coming_soon.jpg>` that should be quoted.

Comment: That's contrary to the actual behavior. What I meant is, try `var_dump($row['picture'])` inside your loop to see what the actual value is (since the behavior indicates that it's a blank string).

Comment: I have this same code used in another part of this file, but it is only pulling one possible image.  It works correctly there.  Because this is pulling multiple images, I wonder if that is the issue?

Comment: I think the problem lies here: `ON product_image.giftID='products.giftID'`. That's looking for a `product_image` where the `giftID` is a literal string of "products.giftID", rather than the product's id. That probably returns a blank string for the image.

Comment: so my query is incorrect?  I am trying to pull data from two tables

Comment: you should be able to tell if the query is correct by dumping out the contents of $row

Answer (score 1):

Your query joins the `product_image` table where `product_image.giftID='products.giftID'`.
I assume you want to match the numeric ID from the `products` table rather than a literal string.

I suggest removing the quotes from `'products.giftID'`:

```sql
SELECT products.giftID, products.gift_name, products.price, products.short_description, 
       product_image.picture
  FROM products
  LEFT JOIN product_image ON product_image.giftID = products.giftID
                          AND products.vendorID = 1
```

Comment: You are fantastic!!!  That worked.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

@showdev has it right. (I made this answer Community Wiki so as not to steal his credit.)

```
LEFT JOIN product_image   ON product_image.giftID='products.giftID' /*wrong*/
                         AND products.vendorID='1'
```

is no good, because it looks for a `product_image` row with a `giftID` column equal to the text string 'products.giftID'.   You want this, without the single quotes in the first line.

```
LEFT JOIN product_image   ON product_image.giftID=products.giftID
                         AND products.vendorID='1'
```

**Also**:

Your HTML code generation is incorrect. You're getting

```
<img src=product_img/image_coming_soon.jpg>  <!-- wrong -->
```

The attribute values inside your `<img ...>` tags have to be surrounded by *double quotes*. (Some browsers, accidentally, accept other punctuation.) You want stuff like this in your html:

```
<img src="product_img/image_coming_soon.jpg">
```

So, you need

```
{echo '<img src="product_img/image_coming_soon.jpg">';}
else {echo '<img src="' . $row['picture'] . '">';}
```

You can put double quotes inside php single quotes.